# difference between these sql joins (same results, same exec plans)

Tags: mysql, sql, join, inner-join, natural-join

Two tables. First table holds every person, another table is used to specify which person is a kid as part of a family:

```
create table persons(
    personID bigint primary key auto_increment,
    firstName varchar(30) not null,
    lastName varchar(30) not null
);

create table kids(
    personID bigint not null,
    familyID bigint not null,
    grade bigint,

    constraint kidReference foreign key (personID) references persons (personID),
    constraint familyReference foreign key (familyID) references families (familyID)
);
```

I want to select all details for each person that is a kid. Using the following queries, i get the same result, the same **identical** execution plan:

**(1)** comma separated join:

```
select persons.personID, persons.firstName, persons.lastName, kids.familyID, kids.grade from persons, kids where persons.personID = kids.personID;
```

**(2)** natural join:

```
select * from persons natural join kids;
```

**(3)** named join:

```
select * from persons join kids using (personID);
```

**(4)** condition join:

```
select * from persons inner join kids on persons.personID = kids.personID;
```

Is it a matter of mere readability? And when writing queries should i aim for just for -what-it-works-best-?

Comment: You  should avoid commas in the `from` clause (this is archaic syntax replaced by the more powerful `join`/`on` clauses) and `natural join` (bugs waiting to happen).  Otherwise, choose the appropriate join for the problem at hand and the syntax you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, each version of the query will result in the same basic query.

The comma syntax will try to find a join based on the WHERE clause. `where persons.personID = kids.personID` becomes `inner join kids on persons.personID = kids.personID`. Note that `=` causes inner join and `*=` causes left join.

The natural join looks to join on columns which have the same name, i.e. `PersonID`. You don't need to specify a specific name as natural join will find common names for you. The default is an inner join.

The named join `using (PersonID)` is shorthand for joining both tables on  column name `PersonID` which they both share. `JOIN` on its own is interpreted as an  inner join.

And the final version is spelling out exactly what you want, with no need for interpretation.

My preference is for the final version because it has no surprises.

Having said that, `JOIN using (personID)` is also unambiguous - it's just shorthand for the final version.

Comment: Great answer, just 2 things: **1)** avoid the old style joins (1st version), it is deprecated since 1992. **2)** The 4th form is the one specified in the standard, the 2nd and 3rd ones are not supported by other RDMBSes.

Comment: @Pred Those are good points.. @hrs Be cautious of `natural join` as Gordon Linoff said. Eg, two tables might both have column `id` as a primary key which increments by 1 for each new row. A join behind the scenes on `id` based purely on name, would be logically wrong.